# Visual Studio WP design inside ScrollViewer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am designing an app for Windows Phone using the Viual Studio XAML designer. My page is to long to fit into a page so I had to put it inside a ScrollViewer and Grid. This works but my problem is that the designer does not allow me to see (and therefore to some extent interact) with these elements outside the page. Is there any setting or something that I can use to be able to interact with these elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the XAML element of the page:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DesignHeight="<desired height>"
```

i.e.:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    d:DesignHeight="1600"
    ....more attributes...
    >

    <!-- other stuff -->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The xml namespace definition for "d" is probably already present, and the same can be done for the design time width, of course.

Comment: This seems to work but after I run the application the page simply goes back to being cut off and I have to remove and add the designheight property again, why is this?

Comment: @Gerhman: Indeed it does, I didn't know that. And it's not something I an answer to, to be honest. Adjusting the DesignHeight makes it work again, but that's not some solution...
If find out anything I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it but this already allows me to do what I want albeit with more effort.

Comment: The same bug occurs with my VS as well, if I change to another file then change back to my xaml, the overflowed area disappears.